# How to fade gradient, image or texture as background?

Tags: html, css

Very new to css and html and using html5/css3 pages.

How can I apply a gradient or image similar to the following (is that an image or texture) and fade it down the page accordingly?

[image]

I have been trying similar gradients like this but seems to only apply to color and not a grid/grille effect.

```
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code ,

```
    <div class="grilleLayer"><div>

    .grilleLayer
    {
        width:100%;
        height:700px;
    background:url('http://s8.postimg.org/90qdtbn1t/temp.png') repeat scroll left top; 
    }


    body
    {
    background: #e0e5e1; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e0e5e1 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#e0e5e1), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));         /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e0e5e1 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #e0e5e1 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #e0e5e1 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #e0e5e1 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0e5e1', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pn2y/2/) !

or

You can generate your desire gradient color [HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's awesome.  The gradient looks good but there is no grille effect as illustrated in my photo. How can I get that grille effect in there?

Comment: JaJ , I've edit my answer , you can change the image as smaller as you wish !

Answer (score 1):

The grid effect can be achieved using secondary gradient on a wrapper div, with very small color stops. [Here's an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/aGXeq/):

```
body
{
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px);
    background-size: 2px 2px;
}
```

I'd stick to using a small texture, though, and use a CSS gradient for the main background, since you have more control of the texture images than of CSS gradients (especially that patterns such as the one you want usually need to be pixel-perfect).

Comment: agree, creating the grid effet with css gradient will be less efficient than using small texture file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I don't see the grille effect in that example? Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/aGXeq/